# Reactjs: Unknown why function re-run second time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-context

I started learning react, yesterday I ran into this issue, somebody please explain me.
When I click button "add to wishlist" the piece of code below run 1st time, set product property "inWishList": true, but unknown why it rerun and set it back to "false" value.

```
 const AddToWishList = (id) => {
    setProducts((prev) => {
      const latest_Products = [...prev];
      const selected_Prod_Id = latest_Products.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
      latest_Products[selected_Prod_Id].inWishList =
        !latest_Products[selected_Prod_Id].inWishList;

      console.log(latest_Products);
      return latest_Products;
    });
  };
```

_ The piece of code below works perfect, run only 1 time, however, i don't understand the difference between 2 codes

```
  const AddToWishList = (id) => {
    setProducts((currentProdList) => {
      const prodIndex = currentProdList.findIndex((p) => p.id === id);
      const newFavStatus = !currentProdList[prodIndex].inWishList;
      const updatedProducts = [...currentProdList];
      updatedProducts[prodIndex] = {
        ...currentProdList[prodIndex],
        inWishList: newFavStatus,
      };
      console.log(updatedProducts);
      return updatedProducts;
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet you are mutating the state object when toggling the `inWishList` property.

```
const AddToWishList = (id) => {
  setProducts((prev) => {
    const latest_Products = [...prev];
    const selected_Prod_Id = latest_Products.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);

    latest_Products[selected_Prod_Id].inWishList =
      !latest_Products[selected_Prod_Id].inWishList; // <-- state mutation

    console.log(latest_Products);
    return latest_Products;
  });
};
```

The second snippet you not only shallow copy the previous state, but you also shallow copy the element you are updating the `inWishList` property of.

```
const AddToWishList = (id) => {
  setProducts((currentProdList) => {
    const prodIndex = currentProdList.findIndex((p) => p.id === id);
    const newFavStatus = !currentProdList[prodIndex].inWishList;

    const updatedProducts = [...currentProdList]; // <-- shallow copy state

    updatedProducts[prodIndex] = {
      ...currentProdList[prodIndex], // <-- shallow copy element
      inWishList: newFavStatus,
    };

    console.log(updatedProducts);
    return updatedProducts;
  });
};
```

Now the reason these two code snippets function differently is likely due to rendering your app into a `StrictMode` component.

[StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Specifically in reference to [detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - *Functions passed to **`useState`**, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`*

When you pass a function to `setProducts` react actually invokes this twice. This is exposing the mutation in the first example while the second example basically runs the same update twice from the unmutated state, so the result is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks you @DrewReese , so 2 code snippet above all run twice however the 2nd code snippet return the result I expected. What methods in function component should I use, please explain me more by writing function to void this issue.

Comment: @J.Tran Your second snippet is the correct way to update state since it is shallow copying the bits of state it is updating. Could it be written a little more cleanly? Sure.   Otherwise, not much else to say really. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, as you stated I can use other functions: useMemo, useReducer, I guess there are better way to write my code wisely. Btw, what I expect more : is there a method I can debug this issue or aware myself of this issue, I might run into this issue again in future.

Comment: @J.Tran Ah, I see, `useMemo` and `useReducer` are other React hooks that serve different purposes. Though unrelated to redux, you may find [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) useful. The pattern applies generally to updated nested React state since React uses shallow reference equality checks as part of its reconciliation process (i.e. what actually updated and needs to be flushed to the screen). BTW, has my answer sufficiently addressed/resolved your original question?

Comment: Yes, thank you @DrewReese for explanation, I think I need write more code and do more react projects, to get used to react concepts.

Comment: @J.Tran Read the React docs.... and read the React docs again... and again... I've been using React for about 4 years and I still refer back to the docs almost daily and ***still*** occasionally find new information.